# Clear local cabal repository

Tags: haskell, cabal

After forcefully installing the latest "bytestring" package I've stumbled into a dependency hell. I want to wipe all local packages out, so that I could re-`cabal-install` them after.

What is the correct way of doing that? Is there a better way of recreating the local repository?

Comment: Cabal seriously needs to get its s*** together. I can't believe how easy it is to end up in a dependency hell and how little it does to try to resolve it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On OS X you can clear the following directory:

```
~/Library/Haskell/ghc-XXX/lib/
```

Globally installed packages are in, but they are commonly installed by the Haskell Platform installer, as the default is to install packages for the current user only:

```
/Library/Haskell/ghc-XXX/lib/
```

If you are on Windows or Linux try the following code ([source](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Cabal-Install)) in ghci:

```
:m System.Directory
getAppUserDataDirectory "cabal"
```

The config file there will tell you where you are installing user packages to.

Comment: Thank you. In my case (Ubuntu Linux) deleting `~/.ghc` and `~/.cabal` helped

Comment: On OSX one also has to delete `~/.ghc`